# Stationarity of a time series data

Tags: python, r, time-series, statsmodels

I am trying to model a time series data using ARIMA modelling in python. I  used the function `statsmodels.tsa.stattools.arma_order_select_ic` on the default data series and got the values of p and q as 2,2 respectively. The code is as below,

```
dates=pd.date_range('2010-11-1','2011-01-30')
dataseries=Series([22,624,634,774,726,752,38,534,722,678,750,690,686,26,708,606,632,632,632,584,28,576,474,536,512,464,436,24,448,408,528,
          602,638,640,26,658,548,620,534,422,482,26,616,612,622,598,614,614,24,644,506,522,622,526,26,22,738,582,592,408,466,568,
          44,680,652,598,642,714,562,38,778,796,742,460,610,42,38,732,650,670,618,574,42,22,610,456,22,630,408,390,24],index=dates)
df=pd.DataFrame({'Consumption':dataseries})
df

sm.tsa.arma_order_select_ic(df, max_ar=4, max_ma=2, ic='aic')
```

The Result is as follow,

```
{'aic':              0            1            2
 0  1262.244974  1264.052640  1264.601342
 1  1264.098325  1261.705513  1265.604662
 2  1264.743786  1265.015529  1246.347400
 3  1265.427440  1266.378709  1266.430373
 4  1266.358895  1267.674168          NaN, 'aic_min_order': (2, 2)}
```

But when I use Augumented Dickey Fuller test, the test result shows that the series is not stationary.

```
d_order0=sm.tsa.adfuller(dataseries)
print 'adf: ', d_order0[0] 
print 'p-value: ', d_order0[1]
print'Critical values: ', d_order0[4]

if d_order0[0]> d_order0[4]['5%']: 
    print 'Time Series is  nonstationary'
    print d
else:
    print 'Time Series is stationary'
    print d
```

Output is as follow,

```
adf:  -1.96448506629
p-value:  0.302358888762
Critical values:  {'5%': -2.8970475206326833, '1%': -3.5117123057187376, '10%': -2.5857126912469153}
Time Series is  nonstationary
1
```

When I cross verified the results with R, it showed that the default series is stationary. Then why did the augumented dickey fuller test result in non stationary series?

Comment: adfuller doesn't reject that there is a unit root. This could also mean that there is not enough power to reject the unit root hypothesis even if the process is stationary. What did you use in R you "show" the series is stationary?

Comment: I just used auto.arima(y) in R whic gave me the result (1,0,1) but in python adfuller test depicts the series y as nonstationary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly you have some seasonality in your data. Then arma models and stationarity tests need to be carefully done.

Apparently, the reason for the difference in adf test between python and R is the number of default lags each software uses.

```
> (nobs=length(dataseries))
[1] 91
> 12*(nobs/100)^(1/4)  #python default
[1] 11.72038
> trunc((nobs-1)^(1/3)) #R default
[1] 4
> acf(coredata(dataseries),plot = F)

Autocorrelations of series ‘coredata(dataseries)’, by lag

     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11 
 1.000  0.039 -0.116 -0.124 -0.094 -0.148  0.083  0.645 -0.072 -0.135 -0.138 -0.146 
    12     13     14     15     16     17     18     19 
-0.185  0.066  0.502 -0.097 -0.151 -0.165 -0.195 -0.160 
> adf.test(dataseries,k=12)

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  dataseries
Dickey-Fuller = -2.6172, Lag order = 12, p-value = 0.322
alternative hypothesis: stationary

> adf.test(dataseries,k=4)

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  dataseries
Dickey-Fuller = -6.276, Lag order = 4, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary

Warning message:
In adf.test(dataseries, k = 4) : p-value smaller than printed p-value
> adf.test(dataseries,k=7)

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  dataseries
Dickey-Fuller = -2.2571, Lag order = 7, p-value = 0.4703
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

Comment: But even by specifying lag order=12. The series remains nonstationary, and the test result is ,adf=-1.96448506629, p= 0.302358888762, which is significantly different from lag 12 result from your answer. And on what basis should i select lag order.

Comment: There is another set of data for which both R and Python shows it as nonstationary. If lag is taken as 4 for this series in python. It becomes stationary. How actually lag is considered?

Comment: this is the series mentioned above [
9560,4010,3790,3840,9150,10230,9570,8230,4640,3730,5820,10410,10220,10040,6720,4290,3820,8700,10040,10820,10080,4160,4320,4140,
9360,10000,10410,7830,9640,3950,5130,9420,9590,9070,10950,10320,3640,4260,10270,10380,9230,10750,10410,5160,5540,11160,11000,11110,
9850,867,4830,5100,10680,11290,10930,10410,10380,4300,4270,10550,9170,13158,12407,10111,5997,5083,10577,10464,10592,11908,11150,
5867,5571,12262,11099,8584,8980,11391,6135,5638,11030,9080,12454,10899,10706,5259,5731,11392,9920,11640,11401
]

Comment: See the autocorrelation funtion acf with plot=TRUE, the 7th lag is significant

Comment: adfuller with fixed lag and constant and trend `sm.tsa.adfuller(a, maxlag=12, autolag=None, regression='ct')` reports the same test statistic as in Robert's answer, but the p-value differs and is based on extrapolation and not exact.